# Save folder name as variable in a loop using bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have multiple folders and I'm trying to save each folder name as a varible for downstream use in a loop:

```
for f in TINKER*;
do
    name=$(echo $f | sed 's/TINKER_more([0-9]+)_less([0-9]+)/TINKER_$1_$2/')
    echo $name
done
```

Folder examples:

```
TINKER_more05_less23
TINKER_more55_less218
TINKER_more23_less03
```

In the case of the first folder above, I want echo $name to output: TINKER_05_23

For some reason, I have been getting empty output from echo $name.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: `+` in POSIX BRE matches a literal  `+`. Add `-E` option after `sed`. And use `\n`, not `$n`, in the replacement. It is `sed`, not `perl`. `sed -E 's/TINKER_more([0-9]+)_less([0-9]+)/TINKER_\1_\2/'`

Comment: You can use pure bash for that: `for f in TINKER*; do [[ $f =~ TINKER_more([0-9]+)_less([0-9]+) ]] && echo TINKER_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}; done`.

Comment: You'd probably find saving them in an array more useful than a set of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` in POSIX BRE regex matches a literal `+` char. You need to add an `-E` option to make `sed` use the POSIX ERE syntax.

Besides, you need to use `\n`, not `$n`, in the replacement. `perl` uses `$n` replacement backreference syntax, but `sed` uses `\n`.

So you need

```sh
sed -E 's/TINKER_more([0-9]+)_less([0-9]+)/TINKER_\1_\2/'
```

When [testing](https://ideone.com/mtAGpO) with the above data,

```sh
fldrs="TINKER_more05_less23 TINKER_more23_less03 TINKER_more55_less218"
for f in $fldrs; do
 name=$(echo "$f" | sed -E 's/TINKER_more([0-9]+)_less([0-9]+)/TINKER_\1_\2/');
 # OR
 # name=$(sed -E 's/TINKER_more([0-9]+)_less([0-9]+)/TINKER_\1_\2/' <<< "$f");
 echo "$name"
done
```

The output is

```
TINKER_05_23
TINKER_23_03
TINKER_55_218
```

**Additionally**, if you want to do it in pure Bash:

```sh
rx='TINKER_more([[:digit:]]+)_less([[:digit:]]+)'
for f in TINKER*; do 
    if [[ "$f" =~ $rx ]]; then
        echo "TINKER_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
done
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/GCb3oV) yielding `TINKER_05_23`, `TINKER_23_03` and `TINKER_55_218` again.

The `TINKER_more([[:digit:]]+)_less([[:digit:]]+)` regex contains two capturing groups defined with two pairs of unescaped parentheses, and the
`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` contains the contents of Group 1 and `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` contains the value in Group 2.

Answer (score 4):

Bash has a built-in match operator `=~`, so you don't need `sed` for that. You can write your snippet in pure Bash, like the following:

```sh
for f in TINKER*; do 
    if [[ $f =~ TINKER_more([0-9]+)_less([0-9]+) ]]; then
        echo TINKER_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    fi
done
```

The code above will result in the following output for the files you posted:

```
TINKER_05_23
TINKER_23_03
TINKER_55_218
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ name=$(sed 's/_[^0-9]*\([^_]*\)/_\1/g' <<< $f)
```